# Magento 1.7 - Product Import - Images do not load

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have been trying to import products into Magento and images.  The products are being imported and created properly but the images to not get imported.

I am aware of the basics of importing as I have done it in the past but cannot figure out what the issue is and what to do next.

some notes how and what I did:

- I am aware to add a "/" before the image name
- image name is case sensitive
- upload images in media/import folder
- media folder to be 777
- Tried different folders like var/import or
  media/catalog/product/import
- Removed the .htcaccess file in media
- Flushed cache
- when i upload manually an image on a product it does show up properly
- i tried specifying the _media_attribute_id in a column as 88 maybe
  that should help but it didn't

Comment: provide the part of the file you are trying to upload. Is there any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Mage_Catalog_Model_Product, all you need to do is this:

```
$fn = '/absolute/path/to/image.jpg';
$types = array('thumbnail', 'small_image', 'image'); // or null if you already have the product's thumbnail, small image, and image set
$move = true;                                        // move the source file, don't leave it sitting around
$exclude = false;                                    // enabled in product view
$label = 'Turquoise';

$product->addImageToMediaGallery($fn, $types, $move, $exclude);  // Strictly speaking, only the first parameter is required

if(!empty($label)) {
    $gallery = $product->getData('media_gallery');
    $gallery_img = array_pop($gallery);
    $gallery_img['label'] = $label;
    array_push($gallery['images'], $gallery_img);
    $product->setData('media_gallery', $gallery);
}

$product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem while uploading product image. And i tested many methods to figure that out. But nothing helped me. At last in one of the tutorial I have seen that the image name and the sku name has to be same. with the extension of file extension. So i followed it and by God's grace it worked. You may try that also. It worked for me. I had spent almost one full day to figure that out.